# CLLocationManager always locates London

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have the following lines of code to locate my position, but I always get the the same location regardless of where I am:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray    *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    self.lati = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: are you testing in device ? or simulator??

Comment: on which iOS version are you testing?

Comment: The simulator does not give the right coordinates.

Comment: The first item in the simulator (Xcode is London in the drop down menu).. so you might have selected it.. check it out..

Comment: that what it was...Thx Reno

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method in place of your delegate method. It will work for you.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    myLatitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    myLongitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"LAT AND LON IS %f %f",myLatitude,myLongitude);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in .h write

<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

then this also

CLGeocoder *geocoder;
CLLocationManager *locationManager;        

then in .m

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;

locationManager.delegate = self;
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

and then implement its delegates

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];

userCoordinate=newLocation.coordinate;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:userCoordinate.latitude
                                         forKey:@"userLat"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:userCoordinate.longitude
                                         forKey:@"userLong"];

CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks)
    {
        NSString *cityName = @"";
        NSString *countryName = @"";
        cityName = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
        countryName = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];


        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setObject:cityName forKey:@"CityName"];
        [prefs setObject:countryName forKey:@"CountryName"];
    }
}];

[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];

if(error.code == kCLErrorDenied)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You          have to select \"Allow\" for current location." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.tag = 888;
    [alert show];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0.0
                                         forKey:@"userLat"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0.0
                                         forKey:@"userLong"];

[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```